# express-ws and socket.io gets a 404 on connection

Tags: node.js, sockets, express

I'm trying to build a web page that uses web sockets to discuss with a server in NodeJS. For the client, nothing fancy :

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8081');
```

For the server, I'm using "express" (because I'd like to have a /login route) but I'm having some trouble. Indeed, when I try to connect with the line above, I get a 404 to "http://localhost:8081/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LGRAhbD". I guess that "express" does not know the route although I'm using "express-ws". Here is my code:

```
var express = require("express");

var app = express();
var http = require("http").Server(app);
var expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);

var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
var socketJwt = require('socketio-jwt');

app.use(function(req, res, next)
{
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    next();
});

var io = require("socket.io")(http);

app.ws('/', function(ws, req)
{
    ws.on('connection', function(socket)
    {
        console.log('plip');
    });

    console.log('plop');
});

app.listen(8081);
```

Note that I tried to make a simple server using "socket.io" and it works. It just fails when I introduce "express". I tried to create a route to "/socket.io" but it does not work either.